# How do I push back to a vector<vector<Object>> in which I have only reserved memory?

Tags: c++, oop, stl

So I have a member `vector<vector<Foo>> _meshMatrix` 
If I do

```
_meshMatrix.resize(_numRefElementsPerRow);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _numRefElementsPerRow ; i++)
        _meshMatrix [i].resize(_numRefElementsPerColumn);
```

then I have a matrix of `Foo` objects and I can access its elements with  `[][]`

```
for(unsigned int row = 0; row < _numRefElementsPerRow; row++)
    for(unsigned int column = 0; column < _numRefElementsPerRow; column++)
        _meshMatrix [row][column] = someFooObject;
```

Instead of that to save memory since  some matrix positions won't be filled up , I want to used `reserve` and `push_back`, so

```
_meshMatrix.reserve(_numRefElementsPerRow);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _numRefElementsPerRow ; i++)
        _meshMatrix [i].reserve(_numRefElementsPerColumn);
```

but I don't know how to push_back twice into this matrix

```
for(unsigned int row = 0; row < _numRefElementsPerRow; row++)
    for(unsigned int column = 0; column < _numRefElementsPerRow; column++)
        //_meshMatrix.??? = someFooObject; // how dO I use push_back here?
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your loop to reserve uses `_meshMatrix [i]` when the size of `_meshMatrix` is *zero*. And there's no difference in memory consumption between resizing and reserving for a vector.

Comment: _"some matrix positions won't be filled up"_ — Does it mean that the matrix is sparse? Are those "zeros" only at the end of rows, or even in the middle? There are special formats for sparse matrices which are likely better than just a vector of vectors.

Comment: @DanielLangr  It's like filling a big polygon drawn inside a rectangole with litte polygons

Comment: @DanielLangr what formats are those?

Comment: By the way, the first `resize` call and the loop is really the same as the single statement `_meshMatrix = std::vector<std::vector<Foo>>(_numRefElementsPerRow, std::vector<Foo>(_numRefElementsPerColumn));`

Comment: And as I mentioned `myVector.resize(X)` and `myVector.reserve(X)` really allocates the exact same memory. The difference being that `resize` sets the size and default-initialized the elements, while `reserve` only allocates. So unless `Foo` does some internal memory allocations on construction, there's no difference between `resize` and `reserve`, memory-wise.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Storage formats for sparse matrices. There are many of them and the suitability of particular ones highly depends on the application. The most simple is that you store matrix elements as a sequence of element values (`Foo` in your case) together with their row and column coordinates. Or, you can store for each row only its "nonzero" elements as a sequence of `Foo` with their column coordinates.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right, I wanted to avoid initializing everything because then there will be a lot of spaces that I would have to remove from the vector. what I have to do is sampling   a rectangle  containing a polygon left to right and bottom to top, with a smaller rectangle. When it is inside the polygon, I would add it to my vector of vector.

Comment: Now That I think about it How would I recognize how many elements will I have in each row at the end? I will have the coordinates of each small rectangle so I don't care about keeping its position along a row

Comment: As mentioned by @DanielLangr what you seem to want is a *sparse matrix*. Please do some research about that. There should be plenty of tutorials and examples online.

Comment: What do you mean by "because then there will be a lot of spaces that I would have to remove from the vector"? If you remove them by replacing them with an empty element, that is already done. If you erase them, then the positions of elements after the erased one are not kept (and that operation is slow). `std::vector` wraps a continuous array, it's not a map or something.

Comment: If the matrix is "mostly populated" then the simplest solution would be to `resize` the outer collection, and for each collection within that has values, `reserve` and push-back items (you could reserve all of them if there's enough memory). Otherwise maybe consider using something different for the outer collection such as a list, map, or vector of key-value pairs, depending on how you need to insert/access the elements.  You don't _have_ to use the same collection type for rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

`_meshMatrix [row].push_back(value)`

Fyi you are using `_numRefElementsPerRow` to iterate over both the rows and the columns <s>and to reserve space for the columns. Unless they are both the same size this is an error.</s>  I think you meant to use `_numRefElementsPerColumn`.

---

EDIT: It seems I made an assumption about your code that was incorrect. I'll walk through your code.
EDIT2: I shouldn't do this late at night. Typoed reserve -> resize. Fixed.

```
vector<vector<Foo>> _meshMatrix;
_meshMatrix.reserve(_numRefElementsPerRow);
```

Calling resize default initializes `_numRefElementsPerRow` elements of `vector<Foo>`. The memory is allocated and constructed.

Calling reserve here allocates enough memory to hold `_numRefElementsPerRow` elements of `vector<Foo>`. This does not mean that any elements have been constructed; you have only made sure that there would be enough room for that many in the row vector. Note that I refer to it as the row vector because you allocate it to hold the number of elements in a row via _numRefElementsPer**Row**

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _numRefElementsPerRow ; i++)
        _meshMatrix [i].reserve(_numRefElementsPerColumn);
```

Next you reserve enough memory for each column. **However** you've missed a step. This is undefined behaviour. You are calling `resize` on objects that haven't been constructed yet. If you were to call `_meshMatrix.size()` it would return `0`. To create the objects, you must construct them, for instance this is valid:

```
    vector<vector<Foo>> _meshMatrix;
    _meshMatrix.reserve(_numRefElementsPerRow);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _numRefElementsPerRow ; i++) {
        _meshMatrix.push_back(); // <<< construct a vector<Foo> at the end
        _meshMatrix[i].reserve(_numRefElementsPerColumn);
```

Now if you want to add the elements for each column, you can do it like so:

```
for (unsigned j = 0; j < _numRefElementsPerColumn; j++) {
    _meshMatrix[j].push_back(value); // <<< some value
}
```

Putting it together:

```
    // Create empty vector for rows
    vector<vector<Foo>> _meshMatrix;
    // Allocate memory ahead of time for the elements
    _meshMatrix.reserve(_numRefElementsPerRow);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _numRefElementsPerRow ; i++) {
        // Create a vector for column values
        _meshMatrix.emplace_back(); // or _meshMatrix.push_back({});
        // Allocate memory ahead of time for the elements
        _meshMatrix[i].reserve(_numRefElementsPerColumn);
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < _numRefElementsPerColumn; j++) {
            // Add values
            _meshMatrix[j].push_back(value); // <<< some value
        }
    }
```

Comment: `_meshMatrix[row]` does not exist inside the loop. You should provide more details about your solution.

Comment: what is i ? the row index (external for) or the column one (internal for).

Comment: Sorry, typo. I mean row

Comment: Still don't see how to move in the matrix with that statement

Comment: how do I select a position (row, column ) ? Why is the column index not showing up?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO A vector must have at least `i` elements to put one at its `i-1`-th position. Reserving memory does not change anything about it.

Comment: Push_back adds to the back of a vector. You are storing the values as first rows and then the inner vector as the column values. The expression `_meshMatrix[row]` returns a reference to a column vector. By pushing back on the column vector you are adding the column value.

Comment: @Daniel Langr I assumed that the full code wasn't shown. Daniel is right that you need to actually add vectors to  _meshMatrix before you can add values to columns. Is this being done?

Comment: @Stewart Smith so if I understand well your second to last comment( under my post). The column index is essentially to know how many time I should push back on each row, right?

Comment: btw you said _meshMatrix[row] returns a reference to a column vector , did you meant a reference to a row vector? Or the interpretation is arbitrary?

Comment: Once the vector of vector is filled each one having a different number of elements per row, if I  want say, plot it, how can I know how many elements are there in each column? Is not like a string with a null terminated character that  would let me know

Comment: See my edit. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can push_back like this

```
for(unsigned int row = 0; row < _numRefElementsPerRow; row++)
{
    vector<Foo> meshMatrixCols;
    for(unsigned int column = 0; column < _numRefElementsPerRow; column++)
         meshMatrixCols.push_back(someObject); // how dO I use push_back here?

     _meshMatrix.push_back(meshMatrixCols);
}
```

Comment: No, you can't, because `_meshMatrix[row]` does not exist according to OP's code.

Comment: I think here rows reserved `_meshMatrix.reserve(_numRefElementsPerRow);`

Comment: Reserve does not add elements. Therefore, you cannot access them.

Comment: Reserved elements can be accessed by index. because on reserve memory allocated.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. Access memory that has not been initialized is a malformed program. Allocated does not mean initialized.

Comment: Yes you are right but [] operator don’t check inbounds. And some how it works :)

Comment: @Villance _"Reserved elements can be accessed by index."_ — No, they can't. _"Somehow it works"_ — It's the worst possible reasoning. You don't even know what `Foo` is. In all cases, you are trying to use objects that haven't been constructed/initialized.

Comment: Yes you said correct I will try to change solution

Comment: I think now it is ok

Comment: @Villance "somehow it works" until it doesn't. Compilers are allowed to optimize assuming undefined behaviour does not exist because its the programmer's responsibility to not create undefined behaviour. This can lead to horrific bugs.

Comment: @Villance Going like "it is UB but it works somehow" is a a very bad advice. This produces just the kind of bugs that are really hard to fix later on.

Comment: You likely want `_meshMatrix.push_back(std::move(meshMatrixCols));`.

Comment: Yes `std::move` is a better choice.